# Promise error when querying Stardog with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stardog

Trying to query a locally run Stardog database from a Node JS application.

The query returns results when run in the Stardog interface.

When running it in Node, something gets messed up with the promise which returns null and an error.

```
(node:1248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null
(node:1248) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The code i'm running in Node is:

```
const { Connection, query } = require('stardog');

const conn = new Connection({
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:5820',
    auth: {
        user: 'admin',
        pass: 'admin'
    }
});

var q = 'select distinct ?s where { ?s ?p ?o }'

query.execute(conn, 'hospital_db', q, {
}).then(({ body }) => {
  console.log(body.results.bindings);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling error in promise.

```
query.execute(conn, 'hospital_db', q, {
}).then(({ body }) => {
  console.log(body.results.bindings);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, still returns null but that might be another problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a catch to your promise chain.

```
 query.execute(conn, 'hospital_db', q, {
    }).then(({ body }) => {
        console.log(body.results.bindings);
    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Stardog.js's Connection object accepts endpoint, username, password, and meta objects, whereas you have an `auth` object. You can see this in the docs at https://github.com/stardog-union/stardog.js#connectionoptions

Comment: No difference when removing the auth obj.